# IIS 7.5 error the requested resource can't be accessed

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I'm trying to sort out my issue. i give all configuration issue but still getting this error

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Config Error This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".  
Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSetup1\web.config 

</modules>
  116:   <handlers>
  117:    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
```

I also give access   to Allow and in module also but still getting this error
using window 7 with IIS 7.5 + ASP.Net 3.5
any idea?

Comment: **IIS Manager -> Feature Delegation**. Try "Read/Write" for "Handler Mappings"

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7.5 is a bear when it comes to user permissions. I would check that the defaultapppool or whatever your IIS user is for your app has permission to access the directory.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <!-- ... -->
    </system.webServer>
```